# How do you reliably process Azure Service Bus messages using a stateless workflow with Standard Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

We have a standard Logic App with a stateless workflow. The trigger is "When messages are available in a queue" for Azure Service Bus and the next step is a For each loop. This combination appears to have a flaw due to limitations and results in two issues.

1. The stateless trigger appears to only allow auto-complete, so on an error all messages are lost.
2. The stateless trigger appears to not allow batching to be configured, so any batch greater than 100 results in the following error.

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each' at line '{line}' and column '{column}': 'The number of foreach items limit exceeded for action 'For_each': maximum '100' and actual '{messageCount}'.'.

Am I missing something here, or are stateful workflows the only reliable way to process Azure Service Bus messages?

Using the `extensions.serviceBus.prefetchCount` configuration in the host.json file it is possible to [limit the number of messages that are read from the queue in a batch](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/azure-logic-apps-running-anywhere-built-in-service-bus-trigger/ba-p/2079995), but due to the limit on the "for each" control action the max number would be 100. *Under load in an ASE using an I1V2 ASP we observed each workflow execution grabbed 66 messages and took ~4 seconds (workflow does some transformations and does an HTTP POST).*

Answer (score -1):

We have tested in our local environment, below statements are based on our analysis.

> 1. The stateless trigger appears to only allow auto-complete, so on an error all messages are lost.

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#triggers), service bus queue support  2 triggers

1. When a message is received in a queue (auto-complete)
2. When a message is received in a queue (peek-lock)

In consumption based logic apps you will have option to select either of the above trigger in your logic designer

Here is the screen shot for reference :

[image]

If you are using standard plan logic app irrespective of either stateful or stateless work flow's  you will have the below service bus queue trigger `When a message is received in a queue` & it doesn't  have any option to confirm whether it is auto-complete or peek-lock .

Here is the screen shot for reference:

[image]

> 2. The stateless trigger appears to not allow batching to be configured, so any batch greater than 100 results in the following
>    error.
>
> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'For_each' at line '{line}' and column '{column}': 'The number
> of foreach items limit exceeded for action 'For_each': maximum '100'
> and actual '{messageCount}'.'.

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#for-each-loop) , `For_each loop` in logic app support only 100 items default if you are using stateless work flow. it support 1,00,000 items if you are using stateful work flows.

Comment: You have mostly echoed the problem, but didn't offer any solutions.